# Remove Woocommerce products but keep categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site which runs using the Woocommerce plugin. I have a large number of products that I need to remove, unfortunately doing this through the Wordpress backend is a very time consuming and frustration process.

I have been looking for a way to remove the products through phpMyAdmin and have found the following

```
DELETE relations.*, taxes.*, terms.*
FROM wp_term_relationships AS relations
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS taxes
ON relations.term_taxonomy_id=taxes.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS terms
ON taxes.term_id=terms.term_id
WHERE object_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='product');

DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product';
```

This works great, accept it also removes the product categories which I would like to keep.

Is there a way to remove all woocommerce products but keep the categories using SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Which table holds the product categories?

Comment: remove the first part of query and run only this - `DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product');
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product';`

Comment: Thanks @Manthan. That does the trick. The only issue I have is that my categories and attributes still have product counts against them, despite the fact that I have removed all the products. Is there a way to remove the products completely so that there are no longer any counts against the categories? Thanks

Comment: ok its confirm that all products are deleted from above use second query only ? if yes then just clear the cache your categoies won't show product counts as we have deleted all the products

Comment: This doesn't seem to work I'm afraid @Manthan. I can confirm the products have been removed. I have then cleared the cache on my browser and viewed the categories in an incognito window. Unfortunately the categories still have a product count attributed to them. Thank you for your continued help

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this MySQL query helped

```
-- Remove all product attributes from WooCommerce
DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy LIKE 'pa_%');
DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy LIKE 'pa_%';
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id not IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy);

-- Delete all WooCommerce products and product variation
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN ('product','product_variation'));
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN ('product','product_variation'));
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN ('product','product_variation');

-- Delete orphaned postmeta
DELETE pm FROM wp_postmeta pm
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE wp.ID IS NULL
```

Taken from [github.com](https://gist.github.com/mikaelz/d574457cb22f1f79f337)